# labels not contained in axis error - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe named df which looks like -

```
pageno     entity          code         rawentity 
17727425   SAUDI           CBCNTRY      saudi 
17727425   GARRA           DRWRNAME     garra
17727425   PO BOX          RBCNTRY      po box 
17727425   NEW ZEALAND     DRWRCNTRY    new zealand
```

I also have a country list containing names of countries.It is of type 'list'.

I'm trying to keep only those value whose code is either - **CBCNTRY** or **RBCNTRY** or **DRWRCNTRY** and the entity should be in the **countrylist**.

The code that I have written is -

```
        for row in df.itertuples():

            if(row.code in ['DRWRCNTRY', 'RBCNTRY', 'CBCNTRY']):
                if(row.entity not in countrylist):
                    df.drop((row.index), inplace=True)
```

But I'm getting the following error -

```
Error is: labels [<built-in method index of Pandas object at 0x0000020A1BCE4EB8>] not contained in axis
```

I just want to know why my approach is wrong and is there any thing better I can do apart from this method.

I have searched this error but I'm unable to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: What is countrylist here?

Comment: You are removing rows as you iterate over your dataframe. You should never do this. See @chuni0r's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Gerardo, use `pd.isin` and combine your expressions using boolean operators:

```
countrylist = ['SAUDI']
codelist = ['DRWRCNTRY', 'RBCNTRY', 'CBCNTRY']
df = df[(df['code'].isin(codelist)) & (df['entity'].isin(countrylist))]
```

results in

```
     pageno entity     code rawentity
0  17727425  SAUDI  CBCNTRY     saudi
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're working with series you can use `pd.isin`. For example, what you want can be achieved by doing:

```
df = df[df['code'].isin(['DRWRCNTRY', 'RBCNTRY', 'CBCNTRY'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` and `isin`

suppose you have list called countrylist that contains SAUDI

```
countrylist = ['SAUDI']
df['code'] = np.where((df['code'] == 'CBCNTRY')| (df['code'] == 'RBCNTRY') | (df['code'] == 'DRWRCNTRY'),
                      df['code'], np.nan
                      )

df['code'] = np.where(df['entity'].isin(countrylist), df['code'], np.nan)

df.dropna(how='any', inplace= True)

print(df)

  pageno entity     code rawentity
17727425  SAUDI  CBCNTRY     saudi
```